# Polygon neighbors

Tags: mathematics, geometry, no-computers

> This question is from the German mathematics competition [Känguru der Mathematik](http://www.mathe-kaenguru.de/index.html). In this competition students have to solve 30 mathematical tasks like this in 90 minutes without calculator. Actually they are given 5 possible answers, but for this community a bit of additional challenge does not hurt.

[image] A regular $15$-gon $A_1 \, A_2 \, ... \, A_{15}$ and a regular $n$-gon $B_1 \, B_2 \, ... \, B_n$ with side lengths of $1$ have a common side: $B_1 B_2 = A_2 A_1$. What value of $n$ makes the distance between $B_3$ and $A_{15}$ be $1$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, note that

> The angles around $A_1$ should sum to 360º.

For the angle inside A,

> Since A is a regular 15-gon, we know each of the interior angles of A measures $\frac{15-2}{15} \times 180^{\circ} = 156^{\circ}$.

For the angle between A and B,

> If $B_3A_{15} = 1$, as we have $B_2B_3 = A_1A_{15} = 1$, then $B_3A_{15}A_2$ is an equilateral triangle, so each of its angles measures 60º.

Therefore, for the remaining angle in B

> The remaining angle from B must measure 360º - 156º - 60º = 144º. Since it is a regular n-gon, all of its interior angles measure $\frac{n-2}{n} \times 180^{\circ}$.
>
>  $\frac{n-2}{n} \times 180^{\circ} = 144^{\circ} \Rightarrow \fbox{n=10}$

Answer (score 4):

By easy angle chasing, the answer is 10.
[image]